# Filtro em combos com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou usando o código abaixo para filtrar valores entre dois combos. O valor do primeiro não aparece no segundo:

```
 $("#treinamento").on('change', function() {
      $("#validade_treinamento").prop('required',true)
      $("#treinamento_2").removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#treinamento_2 option')
         .hide() // esconde
         .filter('[value!="'+$(this).val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .show(); // exibe
 });
```

Mas o que ocorre agora é o seguinte: Não são mais dois combos, mas sim cinco. E os valores não podem aparecer nos combos abaixo. No exemplo abaixo, no combo 2 não aparece para seleção o valor do combo 1, mas no combo 3 aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando essa lógica do código que já tenho, existe como controlar os 5 combos para não aparecerem os valores já selecionados neles?

Answer (score 0):

Para registrar, resolvi da seguinte forma, colocando esse evento em cada campo:

```
 $("#treinamento").on('change', function() {
      $("#validade_treinamento").prop('required',true)
      $("#treinamento_2").removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#treinamento_2 option')
         .hide() // esconde
         .filter('[value!="'+$(this).val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .filter('[value!="'+$("#treinamento").val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .filter('[value!="'+$("#treinamento_3").val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .filter('[value!="'+$("#treinamento_4").val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .filter('[value!="'+$("#treinamento_5").val()+'"]') // filtro das opções diferentes (!)
         .show(); // exibe
 });
```